# TinyTERM Plus - How to move the MainWindow using CScript and/or the TE Control Object

Tags: winapi, terminal-emulator

How can TinyTERM's MainWindow be programmically moved using TinyTERM's CScript and/or TinyTERM's TE Object?

I see the CScript language has a MoveWindow function

```
Void MoveWindow( hWnd, iX, iY, iW, iH bRepaint )
Calls Win32 MoveWindow function.
MoveWindow( hFrame, x, y, w, h, 1 );
```

Does anyone know how to get the MainWindow's hWnd?

I am using Version 4.42.

TinyTERM Plus Programmers Reference Manual
http://www.centurysoftware.com/docs/TinyTERM_Plus_PRM.pdf

Support Page
http://www.centurysoftware.com/support/index.php

I want to Move the MainWindow because I using another program to launch TinyTERM Plus. Currently TinyTERM starts up in the middle of the screen. I would like to move it on top of the application that launched it. Since I am going to have 4 (or more) applications launching a session of TinyTERM it is going to be confusing to have all the TinyTERM session on top of each other. The user will have to manually move them around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TinyTerm .TPX file the following two settings can be used:
xwindow= (Sets the LEFT position of the window)
ywindow= (Sets the TOP position of the window)

This .TPX file is set up in the same format as a .INI file.

This needs to be changed before starting up TinyTerm.

Another setting I used was to change the Window Size:
wwindows= (Change the WIDTH of the window)
hwindows= (Change the HEIGTH of the window)

When this was resized the font also got resized.

This came in handy because the User could define the sized of
the window that started up TinyTerm. Knowing that size allowed
me to set TinyTerm window to the same size.